# Laravel 5.5 login not working on PRODUCTION

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I put my Laravel **5.5** project on production server. And my Login isn't working...

1. I did **key:generate**
2. Then **migrate**
3. Then **db:seed**
4. password was with **bcrypt()**

On localhost everything is working just fine. I didn't change anything in Auth controllers, my login form has **csrf_field**.

The only difference between localhost and production is, that I did **composer install in november on localhost** and **composer install today on production**.

Can anyone please help me, or having similar issue? I haven't find answers anywhere...

Comment: what is the error? what is happening?

Comment: After I submit the login form, nothing happen it just redirect me back on login page. Now i just put **vendor** from localhost to production with ftp, no with composer install and everything is working fine... But anyway i will be glad if anybody can explain me why, because this is just and temporary solution i need to do composer install for better flow in future.

Comment: Compare your `.env` files between local and production. What do you use for session driver?

Comment: It usually just mean your session driver is unable to keep the session of a user. Check your session driver. If it's file, permissions?

Comment: can check domain is added in or not in config/Session

Comment: SESSION_DRIVER=file -> was same on local and production.. @DCoder session domain is default **null**, i didn't specify env SESSION_DOMAIN. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: may be can you add this then check

Comment: @DCoder no it's not working even after add SESSION_DOMAIN to .env

Comment: not in .env there is aanotherfile  config/Session.php

Comment: Do dev and local have same php verison and webserver?